# Run function before exit emacs

Tags: emacs, version-control, org-mode

I want such feature in org-mode: before exiting emacs (while org-mode is running) it asks me: "Do you want to run function vc-dir before exit?" 
I tried this:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'vc-dir)
```

But it errors: "wrong number of arguments"

also tried as found here:

```
(defadvice save-buffers-kill-emacs (before update-mod-flag activate)
(vc-dir))
```

The same error.

- So how to make it work in easy way: vc-dir runs always on exit.
- Or how to make it work with warning message (the best way)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

vc-dir takes an argument (the "dir").

So you can do:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (vc-dir "your-dir-here")))
```

Of course this won't stop emacs from exiting: vc-dir opens a buffer but does not "wait" for user input.  For the interactive approach you want you can do this:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions
          (lambda ()
            (if (y-or-n-p "Do you want to run function vc-dir before exit?")
                (progn
                  (vc-dir "your-directory")
                  nil)
              t)))
```

Change `"your-directory"` by `default-directory` if you want to use the last visited buffer as vc-directory.

Comment: It doesn't work. It closes emacs with message "No files need to be changed", but there are.

Comment: Unfortunately, practically the same behavior. How to make it wait until I make necessary actions and then exit?

Comment: That is what the above snippet does for me; please note that I used `kill-emacs-query-functions`, instead of `kill-emacs-hook`

Answer (score 0):

How about trying that function, which asks for confirmation before running vc-dir:

```
(defun my-vc-check-onexit ()
     (interactive)
     (let ((doquit (read-from-minibuffer "Do you want to run vcs? ")))
       (if (string-equal doquit "y") (vc-dir "~/my/dir"))
       ))
```

and bound it to the hook.

note: it may not be good elisp ;)

Comment: woops, Juanleon's answer (posted as the same time) looks better, and complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same behavior.